# How do I deal with information within arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn the koala gem to link Facebook with my Ruby on Rails application. I'm starting to get the hang of it, but I'm running into some serious mental blocks!

```
def friends
  facebook.fql_query("SELECT uid,username, is_app_user, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user=1");
rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
  logger.info e.to_s
  nil
end
```

So, firstly, I'm using the FQL to search through a users friends. It returns a hash of details of users who are friends of `current_user`, the one signed into the app, and that have also connected with my application.

```
def friends_realname
  names = friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["name"]}
  names.each { |name| puts name}
end
```

I'm selecting the above "user's friends also using my app's" names - and mapping them into an array. This returns an array: `["friend1's name", "friend2's name"]`:

```
def friends_avatars
  @avatars = friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["pic_square"]}
end
```

I'm trying to do the same, but returning the URLs of the profile pictures of those same users. It returns an array:

```
["http://www.example.com/example.jpg", "http://www.example2.com/example2.jpg"]
```

I want to format the information from the returned arrays. So, for the real names, instead of returning the actual array, I want to return a list of names. And, obviously for the images, instead of returning an array of image urls, I actually want to 'puts' those images out in the view.

I'm thinking that I need to iterate through each of these arrays, and then use the `each` method to do something with each string in the array, e.g., puts `img_tag`?

Would something like this be possible?:

```
def friends_avatars
  @avatars = friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["pic_square"]}
  @avatars.each { |avatar| puts image_tag "#{avatar}}"}
end
```

Just realised that `image_tag` is a helper method, so I can't use it there.

I've also tried this in a view file:

```
<% for url in @avatars do %>
  <%= puts "#{url}" %>
<% end %>
```

Which returns:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Anytime I try to return the strings within an array, they just return an array. Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: I've followed Phrogz advice (thanks mate) - and after some testing, I've figured out why I'm getting an error. When I test the class of a method - it returns a class of Array. When I give that method a variable name - that variable name returns NilClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app_users = friends.select{ |f| f["is_app_user"] }
@names_and_pictures = app_users.map{ |f| [ f["name"], f["pic_square"] ] }
```

This creates an array of two-element arrays, i.e.

```
[ [ "Bob", "http://foo" ], [ "Jim", "http://bar" ] ]
```

Then you can iterate these in parallel:

```
<% @names_and_pictures.each do |name,pic_url| %>
  <li><%=name%><img src="<%=pic_url%>"></li>
<% end %>
```

Note that you don't use `puts` in your views, as this function outputs information to the console. Instead, you just use `<%= ... %>` to coerce Ruby code to be a string value and inject it at the appropriate spot in your output.

---

Your original code is nice (insofar as you've wrapped your code in nicely-named methods) but does a little too much.

```
def friends_realname
  names = friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["name"]}
  names.each { |name| puts name}
end
```

There is no need to `puts` the names here. The method only happens to return the correct value because `each` returns the item that was just iterated. Your methods can be written just as effectively as:

```
def friends_realname
  friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["name"]}
end

def friends_avatars
  friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["pic_square"]}
end
```

If you happen to want to keep these methods, you can combine two arrays into one by using `Array#zip`:

```
names   = friends_realname               # One flat array
avatars = friends_avatars                # Another flat array
@names_and_pictures = names.zip(avatars) # An array of two-element arrays
```

Comment: Cheers for that. I'm still getting a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error

Comment: @Samwise Sorry, I failed to make the code an instance variable. Edited.

Comment: I noticed :) I fixed that up before I tested it, and it still has the nilclass error - when ever I get this type of error, I just get stuck!

Comment: The error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` means that somewhere you have `foo.each` and `foo` is not what you expected; it happens to be a `nil` value. If you have a line number, ensure that you are looking on that line to see what variable is being iterated, and then think about how that variable might be `nil`. In this case, it smells like you're putting code in generally the wrong spots (so that the instance variable is not available in your view), or you may be previewing with old data on the server. I cannot reproduce your problem from the limited information supplied.

Comment: I follow you. I'm putting all of this in a model file - perhaps it should go in a controller instead? The line it gives me is in the view file - where: <% @names_and_pictures.each do |name,pic_url| %>

Comment: However, I am now getting a different error, after restarting the server. private method `select' called for nil:NilClass - is it possible these are errors caused due to my ror installations (I've recently had to reinstall everything!)

Comment: I just ran a test - calling @names_and_pictures.class - and the return is nilclass - so I guess, I found my error! Yay me. Next step is to find out why it is returning nil I suppose, any ideas? :)

Comment: I think it may have finally clicked for me. If I want to use a @variable - I must first initialise it. I can do so with attr_accessor :@variable. Without the attr_accessor - it returns a value of Nil - when I include the attr_accessor - it returns the correct class. Correct? :)

Comment: Not correct. This code must go in a controller route, not a model. Instance variables in model methods are not exposed to views.

Answer (score 0):

your calls to map always return an array. so when you do this:

```
@avatars = friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["pic_square"]}
```

you get an array of strings.  For your view purposes, you could do something like this:

```
<% @avatars.each do |url| %>
  <%= puts "#{url}" %>
<% end %>
```

hope that helps

Comment: Using `puts` here is superfluous and noisy on the server. Further, using string interpolation to put a string (or any value) is entirely unnecessary. `puts` and `<%= ... %>` both automatically call `to_s` on any non-string value.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Scott, is that not essentially what I've been doing though? (at the end of my question?) - unfortunately, I'm still running into the same error!